# Extract strings from the URL in response header

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract "state" and "code" from the URL in response header through regular expression.

The RegEx I am using is:

```
state=([^\n]+)\&
code=([^\n]+)
```

Here's the URL:-

```
https://jboss-mxaus.projectsuite.com/?state=205%2F84faf9c7-e4ac-43d1-82e1-d728a4382e1e&code=c3AgHdzZMUbinPX7WZ3xXim9M9A93pGFosZgJmKhvro.14cc8c81-eb44-4a3b-9b5a-5de4a3b6f48f
```

Comment: There is neither explanation nor question here.

Answer (score 0):

I think two separate expressions is easier to maintain two variables,

Use 2 Regular Expression Extractor:

```
Reference Name: state

Regular Expression : state=([^\n]+)&code=([^\n]+)

Template $1$

Match No. 1
```

Second variable:

```
Reference Name: code

Regular Expression : state=([^\n]+)&code=([^\n]+)

Template $2$

Match No. 1
```

It will update state and code variable values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! both are separate parameters.. should I use different expression or the same one

Comment: I think two separate expressions is easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

another version if you want to try

```
  /state=([^&]+)&code=([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$)/
```

based in your comment below, here is how you capture 'state' and 'code' separately

```
let str = "https://jboss-mxaus.projectsuite.com/?state=205%2F84faf9c7-e4ac-43d1-82e1-d728a4382e1e&code=c3AgHdzZMUbinPX7WZ3xXim9M9A93pGFosZgJmKhvro.14cc8c81-eb44-4a3b-9b5a-5de4a3b6f48f";
let result = str.match(/state=([^&]+)&code=([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$)/);

console.log(result[1]);
console.log(result[2]);


result[1] will hold 'state'
result[2] will hold 'code'.
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!both are separate parameters.. should I use different expression or the same one

Comment: what do you mean by separate parameters? you want to have state value in one variable and code value in another?

Comment: Ok. I am editing my response to have those values in two separate params.